# In Solr can we use two diff. fields (min and max) for single range facet?

Tags: solr, search-facet

Currently, I am trying to implement salary range facets like

```
10000-20000  (2)
20001-30000  (100)
50000-60000  (150)
```

However in Sitecore, we have two different fields (`MinSalary` & `MaxSalary`) to store the salary values and I have to use both the fields for the above implementation, for example for the range (10000-20000), `minsalary` should be considered (10000) for left side value and `maxSalary` should be considered (20000) for right side value. Is it possible to use two different fields for single range faceting in Solr? any suggestion here.

Comment: You have to create Computed Index field as per your requirement https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/create-a-computed-index-field.html

Comment: Yes, I have used computed field to get it done. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating computed index fields.

To create a computed index field:

1. Create a class that implements the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IComputedIndexField` interface.
2. Implement simple string properties named FieldName and ReturnType. The FieldName string is the name the field uses in the index.
3. Implement a method called `ComputeFieldValue()`. This method accepts an argument that implements the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.IIndexable` interface and that specifies the data to index. It returns an object that represents the value for the field.

Your class will look like this example:

```
public class MinSalary : IComputedIndexField
{
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        Item item = (Item) (indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem);
        // your logic
    }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public string ReturnType { get; set; }
}
```

4. [Add the computed field to the configuration](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/using-solr-field-name-resolution.html).

Add the field in `AddComputedIndexField` section in search config.

```
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
  <field fieldName="MinSalary" returnType="string">
  Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.CalculatedDimension,Sitecore.ContentSearch
  </field>
  ...
</fields>
```